# Displaylink driver does not work since last update on August 15th 2021, after update and display config changes -> System freezes

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, displaylink, usb-c, docking

[UPDATE] I also tried the Displaylink driver version 5.3.1 from 5th of may 2020. No Monitors externally are detected! So less functionality! I tried this version as well, 'cuz I installed the last working version somewhere in the first half of 2020. Will try now 5.3 and 5.2 (even this is not for UBUNTU 20.04).
[/UPDATE]

[UPDATE2] Drivers 5.2 and 5.3 install/deinstall and reinstall to 5.4 has lead to a system, where external monitors are not detected anyway. So at least the system is now complete broken. I followed that deinstall instructions with

> sudo displaylink-installer uninstall

and rebooted afterwards every time. The installation process does not seem to be very stable.
[/UPDATE2]

I am using a HP USB-C Docking Station for my external periphery devices (USB keyboard and mouse, Audio, Ethernet and 2 External monitors via Displaylink driver), so that I can easily switch between my working laptop running windows 10 and my UBUNTU laptop (ASUS ROG G752VS). Till yesterday's update everything worked fine, after the update, Display link drivers did not work. So I downloaded today the latest Display Link drivers from [here](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1944022-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu-20-0) (I followed all steps). After the rebooting external monitors were detected nearly like before. Now my internal monitor is also detected and I cannot turn it off (either by setting it to "off" on Display settings or by just closing the laptop's lid, the system freezes (You see the monitors with a frozen mouse pointer, and no keyboard). So I cannot even run a terminal hitting "Ctrl-Alt-F[x]".

After system freezes nothing works and you have to turn off the computer by pressing "on" for 4 seconds. I varied switching the main monitor to one of my main (external) displays, which works. But if I turn off any of the monitors (so regardless whether internal or externally attached to the usb-c dock) it freezes. I also tried ARandR to exclude system internal software tooling problems. But the problem seems to lie deep in the system, I assume of the kernel or its display link module.

My HW Configuration:

- Two FULL HD monitors connected via DisplayPort and link to the USB_C dock
- ASUS ROG G752 VS running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- USB Mouse and Keyboard
- Logitech Sound connected analogly to the small jack of the USB-C Dock
- USB-C Dock of HP connected to USB-C/Thunderbolt of my ASUS ROG G752 VS

My SW config:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with last update of Aug 15th
- Display Link driver v.5.4 from synaptics from Apr 6th 2021

Attached the latest updates as a text file (excerpt from /var/log/apt/history.log):

```
    Start-Date: 2021-08-01  18:16:46
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.1473'
Upgrade: virtualbox-6.1:amd64 (6.1.22-144080~Ubuntu~eoan, 6.1.26-145957~Ubuntu~eoan)
Remove: linux-modules-5.8.0-55-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-55.62~20.04.1), linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-55:amd64 (5.8.0-55.62~20.04.1), linux-image-5.8.0-55-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-55.62~20.04.1), linux-modules-extra-5.8.0
-55-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-55.62~20.04.1), linux-headers-5.8.0-55-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-55.62~20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-08-01  18:17:36

Start-Date: 2021-08-15  21:17:05
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libexiv2-27:amd64 (0.27.2-8ubuntu2.4, 0.27.2-8ubuntu2.5)
End-Date: 2021-08-15  21:17:06

Start-Date: 2021-08-15  21:17:10
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-image-5.11.0-25-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-25-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.11.0-25-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-25.27~
20.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-5.11.0-25-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1, automatic), linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-25:amd64 (5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.8.0.63.71~20.04.45, 5.11.0.25.27~20.04.10), linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.8.0.63.71~20.04.45, 5.11.0.25.27~20.04.10), linux-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.8
.0.63.71~20.04.45, 5.11.0.25.27~20.04.10)
End-Date: 2021-08-15  21:18:42

Start-Date: 2021-08-15  21:18:46
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox:amd64 (90.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 91.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-08-15  21:18:52

Start-Date: 2021-08-15  21:18:56
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libgnutls30:amd64 (3.6.13-2ubuntu1.3, 3.6.13-2ubuntu1.6)
End-Date: 2021-08-15  21:18:57

Start-Date: 2021-08-15  21:19:01
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox-locale-en:amd64 (90.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 91.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-08-15  21:19:02

Start-Date: 2021-08-15  23:15:44
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.232'
Install: libjcat1:amd64 (0.1.3-2~ubuntu20.04.1, automatic), libxcb-shm0:i386 (1.14-2, automatic), libllvm12:amd64 (1:12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.3, automatic), libllvm12:i386 (1:12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.3, automatic)
Upgrade: gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 (3.36.1-0ubuntu1, 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1), libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 2.4.105-3~20.04.1), libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 2.4.105-3~20.04.1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-80.90, 5.4.0-81.91), xserver-common:amd64 (2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2, 2:1.20.11-1ubuntu1~20.04.2), alsa-ucm-conf:amd64 (1.2.2-1ubuntu0.8, 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.9), openssl:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.4, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.5), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2, 2:1.20.11-1ubuntu1~20.04.2), sane-utils:amd64 (1.0.32+git20210730-focal0, 1.0.32+git20210811-focal0), libegl-mesa0:amd64 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), openvpn:amd64 (2.4.7-1ubuntu2.20.04.2, 2.4.7-1ubuntu2.20.04.3), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), libglapi-mesa:i386 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), bcompare:amd64 (4.3.7-25118, 4.4.0-25886), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (92.0.4515.107-1, 92.0.4515.131-1), docker-ce-rootless-extras:amd64 (5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal, 5:20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-focal), xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2, 2:1.20.11-1ubuntu1~20.04.2), libxatracker2:amd64 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 (3.36.1-0ubuntu1, 3.36.1-0ubuntu1.1), openssh-sftp-server:amd64 (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.2, 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.3), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), passwd:amd64 (1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04, 1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04.1), libgbm1:amd64 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), xserver-xephyr:amd64 (2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2, 2:1.20.11-1ubuntu1~20.04.2), libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 2.4.105-3~20.04.1), libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 2.4.105-3~20.04.1), libsane1:amd64 (1.0.32+git20210730-focal0, 1.0.32+git20210811-focal0), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:20.04.35, 1:20.04.36), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:20.04.35, 1:20.04.36), libfwupdplugin1:amd64 (1.3.11-1~focal1, 1.5.11-0ubuntu1~20.04.2), ssh:amd64 (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.2, 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.3), xwayland:amd64 (2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2, 2:1.20.11-1ubuntu1~20.04.2), libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 2.4.105-3~20.04.1), libdrm2:i386 (2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 2.4.105-3~20.04.1), login:amd64 (1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04, 1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04.1), openssh-server:amd64 (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.2, 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.3), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), openssh-client:amd64 (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.2, 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.3), libfwupd2:amd64 (1.3.11-1~focal1, 1.5.11-0ubuntu1~20.04.2), shim-signed:amd64 (1.40.4+15+1552672080.a4a1fbe-0ubuntu2, 1.40.6+15.4-0ubuntu7), fwupd-signed:amd64 (1.27.1ubuntu2+1.3.11-1~focal1, 1.27.1ubuntu5+1.5.11-0ubuntu1~20.04.2), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:20.04.35, 1:20.04.36), libsane-common:amd64 (1.0.32+git20210730-focal0, 1.0.32+git20210811-focal0), fwupd:amd64 (1.3.11-1~focal1, 1.5.11-0ubuntu1~20.04.2), libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 2.4.105-3~20.04.1), libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 2.4.105-3~20.04.1), libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 2.4.105-3~20.04.1), libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 2.4.105-3~20.04.1), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.4, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.5), libdrm-dev:amd64 (2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 2.4.105-3~20.04.1), wireless-regdb:amd64 (2020.11.20-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 2021.07.14-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), libsane:amd64 (1.0.32+git20210730-focal0, 1.0.32+git20210811-focal0), docker-ce:amd64 (5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal, 5:20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-focal), mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), docker-ce-cli:amd64 (5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-focal, 5:20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-focal), teamviewer:amd64 (15.20.3, 15.20.6), libglx-mesa0:amd64 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), libglx-mesa0:i386 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 21.0.3-0ubuntu0.2~20.04.1), libdrm-common:amd64 (2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 2.4.105-3~20.04.1), shim:amd64 (15+1552672080.a4a1fbe-0ubuntu2, 15.4-0ubuntu7)
End-Date: 2021-08-15  23:16:59
```

Can anybody give me a hint, what else to try to fix/workaround this issue?
By the way, Does anybody knows, when Display link drivers are flawlessly intergrated into the kernel anyway?
Thanks a lot in advance! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a straight forward solution, as I did not analyse enough the dependency tree here. But I found a solution for fixing my display freezes and the subsequent errors (as a result of my analysing and debugging strategy ;-)) as follows:

1. Dist-Upgraded to 20.10 and 21.04
2. Installed [Mainline](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/mainline-install-latest-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/) tool to install any maintained kernel version easily and graphically
3. Install packages dkms and the proprietary driver of
   [Displaylink 5.4 from 6th Apr 21 for Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu-5.4?filetype=exe)
4. Got dependency errors regarding kernel v.5.13.x Assumed correct
   kernel version by the  by the name of Displaylink driver of synaptic
   : `displaylink-driver-5.4.0-55.153.run`
5. Started mainline tool and downloaded kernel v5.4.0
6. Fixed this version of the kernel in the grub configuration,
   following this instruction [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Submenus):

   - First set GRUB_DEFAULT to "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-050400-generic"
   - Run `sudo update-grub` and get a warning to change this old-fashioned format to the following string literal for version of grub2 bigger than v2.00:
     "gnulinux-advanced-8d93a8c9-e03f-413f-83f8-ea147a14bfcd>gnulinux-5.4.0-050400-generic-advanced-8d93a8c9-e03f-413f-83f8-ea147a14bfcd"
   - You can find out your grub-version by:

     ```
     $ dpkg --list | grep grub
     ii  grub-common             2.04-1ubuntu45
     ```
   - So I had a version bigger than v2.00 (here v2.04 and ergo took the above string and put it into the file /etc/default/grub:

     ````makefile
     $ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

     # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
     # /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
     # For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
     #   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

     #GRUB_DEFAULT=0
     #Set to Kernel 5.4
     #GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-050400-generic"
     GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-8d93a8c9-e03f-413f-83f8-ea147a14bfcd>gnulinux-5.4.0-050400-generic-advanced-8d93a8c9-e03f-413f-83f8-ea147a14bfcd"
     GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
     GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
     GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

     # Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
     # This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
     # the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
     #GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

     # Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
     #GRUB_TERMINAL=console

     # The resolution used on graphical terminal
     # note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
     # you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
     #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

     # Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
     #GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

     # Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
     #GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

     # Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
     #GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"```
     ````
7. Run `sudo update-grub`
8. Now after reboot the correct kernel v5.4.0 was started now in the Ubuntu environment of 21.04 and I could again configure my USB-C external connected monitors with the Ubuntu tools for display config.

Please take into mind that for the solution the kernel version is fixed now and can cause problems in the future with future updates.

I know that this kind of answer is not straight forward but maybe it might help the one or the other, when having such difficulties. It seems that display link driver is fixed to a special kernel version, so it is very unstable against Ubuntu updates. In the end I would suggest, fixing the kernel version to v5.4 would have helped after the update to Ubuntu 20.04 and all other steps are maybe just a waste of time.

Comment: Package of evdi-dkms faces an issue with kernel headers of >5.13 (prototype has a mismatching pointer declaration). So please do not install this package, as it will continously look for the new kernel includes though I decided to use the older kernel v5.4 as mentioned above. If you do not wish to face problems in upgrading the system, please do not install or remove this package. It seems not necessary when using the proprietary drivers.