# External monitors not detected after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10 (Connected via ThinkPad Hybrid USB-C with USB-A Dock)

Tags: 20.04, external-monitor, 21.10, displaylink

I recently upgraded from `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`  to  `Ubuntu 21.10` and now, as the title suggests, my external monitors are no longer detected when connected via the hybrid USB-A cable from the ThinkPad dock mentioned in the title.

I've had external monitor issues in the past, so the first thing I tried was reinstalling DisplayLink drivers: https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu

At first the drivers wouldn't install in the default startup with Wayland (something about EVDI 1.9.1 package or library not found), but I switched to Xorg and then the drivers seemed to install successfully (albeit with a non-fatal error) and prompted a reboot:

```
sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.4.1-55.174.run 
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 5.4.1-55.174  100%  
DisplayLink Linux Software 5.4.1-55.174 install script called: 
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 21.10

Installing

[ Installing EVDI ]
[[ Installing EVDI DKMS module ]]
Error! DKMS tree already contains: evdi-1.9.1
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
EVDI DKMS module already installed.
[[ Installing module configuration files ]]
[[ Installing EVDI library ]]
cc -I../module -std=gnu99 -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o evdi_lib.o evdi_lib.c
cc evdi_lib.o -shared -Wl,-soname,libevdi.so.0 -o libevdi.so.1.9.1 -lc -lgcc 
cp libevdi.so.1.9.1 libevdi.so
[ Installing x64-ubuntu-1604/DisplayLinkManager ]
[ Installing libraries ]
[ Installing firmware packages ]
[ Installing licence file ]
[ Adding udev rule for DisplayLink DL-3xxx/4xxx/5xxx/6xxx devices ]
[ Adding upstart and powermanager sctripts ]

Please read the FAQ
http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/topics/103927-troubleshooting-ubuntu

Installation complete!

Please reboot your computer if intending to use Xorg.
```

Another thing that might be useful to know is the output of

```
xrandr --listmonitors
```

which was:

```
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP-1 1920/276x1080/155+0+0  eDP-1
```

If I connect one of my monitors directly to my laptop via the HDMI cable, it works fine.

Really not sure what else to do here. Hoping I won't have to reinstall 20.04 to get my external monitors working via the dock again.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: There was another user who had an issue with a usb-c cable.  Since you mentioned the HDMI cable working properly, is it possible for you to try a different type of USB cable and or connector rather than the typeC?  If you could that would rule out the connector/cable as an issue.

Comment: I use the same dock and cable on my windows laptop and it works fine. And earlier today, before the update, it was working as well. Also, the wireless mouse and keyboard which are connected to the dock still work when using this cable. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Did you check out the link in the output? http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/topics/103927-troubleshooting-ubuntu

Comment: I would definitely recommend looking at bug reports and checking through the forum for related issues, there seem to be quite a few related to these dual monitors/thinkpad.  Also nvidia drivers if you are using those.

Comment: You can also try checking the logs.  If you have an open terminal you can enter `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and check for output when you connect the monitor.  dmesg may also work.

Comment: On the forums, this error was closest to mine:
https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=67388

I also left a comment on Jonathan Kamen's blog where he posted about a DisplayLink fix on 21.04/21.10: 

https://blog.kamens.us/2021/10/15/displaylink-now-working-for-some-hardware-for-ubuntu-21-04-21-10-nvidia-is-a-problem/

I don't have an NVIDIA GPU, I have intel integrated graphics. Looking at the log was helpful too, it did basically confirm that the DisplayLink driver was failing to start. Thank you all for your help, unfortunately no solution yet...

Comment: You may want to take a look at this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358307/displaylink-driver-does-not-work-since-last-update-on-august-15th-2021-after-up?rq=1

Comment: Fot me it was the display driver (Nvidia) which was updated. I switched to Open source one, and now it all works.